# Validating Interdependent Symfony Constraints: Retrieving Validated Context for Custom Validation

Tags: php, symfony, constraints

I have a DTO object that I create from the global request. In this DTO I have some Symfony constraint validators that I am using, and I have one custom validator to check if the value already exists in the database.

```php
class CreateProjectRequest implements RequestInterface
{
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[Assert\Length(min: 10, max: 10)]
    public string $remoteSource;

    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[UniqueRemoteEntityConstraint]
    public string $remoteReference;
}
```

My constraint validator `UniqueRemoteEntityConstraint` needs the validated value of `remoteSource` before proceeding to check the rest. Right now, I'm getting the violations and checking if there is a violation in it for the `remoteSource` property.

```php
class UniqueRemoteEntityConstraintValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    /**
     * @param UniqueRemoteEntityConstraint $constraint
     */
    public function validate(mixed $value, Constraint $constraint): void
    {
        // Make sure `remoteSource` var is valid
        foreach ($this->context->getViolations() as $violation) {
            if ($violation->getPropertyPath() === 'remoteSource') {
                // Remote source not valid cancel
                return;
            }
        }
        
        // Do checks for uniqueness
    }
}
```

I believe this is sketchy as depending on which way Symfony checks the properties in my DTO it might not have validated it yet. Is there a different way I can make sure the `remoteSource` property is validated first?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this question and answer from me:

[FunctionalTest Validator: Comparison with other property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72808472/functionaltest-validator-comparison-with-other-property/72819884)

You can also note a custom validator directly on the DTO and thus have access to all properties.

**Example**

```php
#[CustomConstraint]
class CreateProjectRequest implements RequestInterface
{
    public string $remoteSource;

    public string $remoteReference;
}

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class CustomConstraint extends Constraint
{
    public function validatedBy(): string
    {
        return CustomValidator::class;
    }

    public function getTargets(): string
    {
        return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT; // <<-- !!!!
    }
}

class CustomValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    /**
     * @param CreateProjectRequest $value
     * @param Constraint $constraint
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        // $value <--- CreateProjectRequest
                       
        $validator = Validation::createValidator();
        
        $violationRemoteSource = $validator->validate(
        $value->getRemoteSource(),
            [
                new NotBlank(),
                new Length()
            ]
        );
                
        $violationRremoteReference = $validator->validate(
            $value->getRremoteReference(),
            [
                new NotBlank(),
                mew UniqueRemoteEntityConstraint()
            ]
        );

        if ($violationRemoteSource->count() > 0
            || $violationRremoteReference->count() > 0
        ) {
            $this->context
                ->buildViolation(
                    'Not valid'
                )
                ->addViolation();
        }               
                       
    }
}
```